# I have tried many times that the login form in 2 steps is not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the outlook login form. The first session will have the user login input field and the second session will have the password input field.

```html
<div class="contanior">
  <div class="main-contanior">
            <div class="logo">
            <img src="login images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <h3>Sign in</h3>
            <form class="form">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Email, phone, or sykpe">
            </form>
            <p>No account?<a href="#">Create one!</a></p><br>
            <div class="sign-in"><a href="#">Sign in with a security key?</a><br></div>
            <div class="option"></div><a href="#">Sign-in option</a><div>       
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form should be one but just separated by div tags, hide the password part using Javascript and CSS, create a next button, make a function in js. this function has to hide the username part and then show the password part when the next button is clicked.

```
<button onclick="Show();">Next</button>
```